# Angular - change size of component/directive dependant on variable passed in

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a spinner that I am wanting to display when loading data, however, I want to be able to have some pre-defined sizes that I can pass in to change the size of the displayed spinner.

For example:

> `<spinner small>` would produce a spinner of size 50px x 50px
>   `<spinner large>` would produce a spinner of size 300px x 300px

Is there any way in which this can be done?

So far, I have a standard spinner with code:

**component.html**

```
<div class="loader middle"></div>
```

**component.css**

```
.loader {
  border: 16px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid red;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
  margin: auto;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tricky but it can be done.

What I usually do is the following :

```
this.size = '120px';
@Input('small') set small(value = 'foo') { // default value is irrelevant
  this.size = !value ? '50px' : this.size;
}
```

Let me explain : we start with a setter input that has a default value (which is irrelevant).

When the user doesn't use small with `<app-spinner small></app-spinner>`, the value will be the default one (here being 'foo').

If the user inputs the small attribute, then the value becomes `''`, which is falsy.

So we test that : if the value is falsy, then we set the value to 50px. If not, we keep the default value of 120px.

In your spinner, use this :

```
<div class="loader" [ngStyle]="{width: size, height: size}"></div>
```

[here is a working demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wjcj3x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Downvoting out of bitterness is just sad. if it isn't the reason, then please comment so that I can improve the answer.

Comment: I understand your concerns about my answer. This fits well to what he describes and seems to be the wanted solution. Sorry for misscomunication :)

Comment: @JonathanStellwag no problem, I was actually answering you while you deleted it, just to say you can keep it as it might help other people : the reason I downvoted is that if other users have the same question, your answer (being a workaround) will be at the bottom, while answers that are answering the question (not necessarily mine) are on top. People usually react too harshly to downvotes, I included !

Comment: It took me a little while to wrap my head around what was going off, but I managed to get things working. Thanks! Here's a simple example of what I was going for: https://stackblitz.com/edit/size-directive-for-div

Comment: @trichetriche Could I just ask if the implementation of different defined sizes for the div is correct, or is there another trick to simplify the input value? Perhaps something like a switch?

Comment: Nice stackblitz ! About the implementation, it is up to you : if this is your project and you want to have several sizes, then maybe you should use a simple `size` input. If you want to be able to quicky change it, or if you have UI guidelines to follow, using this implementation is best suited. As said in unit tests yesterday, *abstracting* a component's logic is best suited to simplify its use and avoid lots of errors.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called **[Attribute Directive](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives)**.

**For example:**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
       el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<p appHighlight>Highlight me!</p>
```

If you are using Angular CLI you can easily generate a new directive by executing this command:

```
ng generate directive highlight
```

Comment: It is a workaround too. he asked to write the selector with a very specific syntax, and you're providing him with another solution.

Comment: I had misunderstood the question, indeed. Have edited my answer. Thanks

Comment: the new answer is irrelevant to the question and partially true, even though not adapted ...

Comment: I couldn't get this to work for some reason. If you could give a stackblitz example?

Answer (score 0):

After attempting the solution @trichetriche had given, I could not get it to work as I had hoped. So after a bit of thinking of how I could achieve what I wanted, I have since managed to solve my problem (elegant or not).

**[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-css-application)**

**component.ts**

```
export class SpinComponent  {
  @Input() size: string;

  displaySize(size: string) {
    switch (size) {
      case 'small':
        return this.getSize(50);
      case 'medium':
        return this.getSize(100);
      case 'large':
        return this.getSize(200);
      default:
        return this.getSize(100);
    }
  }

  getSize(num: number) {
      let myStyles = {
        'width': num + 'px',
        'height': num + 'px'
      };
      return myStyles;
  }  
}
```

**component.html**

```
<div class="loader" [ngStyle]="displaySize(size)"></div>
```

**component.css**

```
.loader {
  border: 5px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 5px solid red;
  /*width: 25px;*/
  /*height: 25px;*/
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```